# Magento price showing twice

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I installed a new template on my Magento store and when I got to a product page it shows the price twice? Most of my products are a "simple" Product and I have one "Configuarable" product

Any ideas how I can get rid of one of the prices?

Here is Simple product:

[image]

Here is configurable product: (with an option selected)

[image]

Any ideas?

I'm running latest 1.9.3.7 and can't find a fix anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your

```
app/design/frontend/default/your _theme/temlate/product/view.phtml
```

1st: inspect  find the class or id

2nd: then remove wrong price code

before doing this take a backup of your file

Comment: I do not have the above in that order I have to go to Catalog/product but when I find the View.phtml the only reference I can find is <script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script> &   <?php if(!$_product_type_center_image){ ?>
                 <div class="price-info">
                     <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
                     <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>

Comment: Commented bottom code out and works perfectly.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone can help you here unless it's a popular theme people would know. The problem is not in Magento, it's in the theme files. You will need to find the theme file and check the php logic to truly know what is happening there. Best case, contact the theme developer if you purchased it or switch to a new theme.

To find the theme file responsible for printing the price, you can enable [template hints](http://dragonfroot.com/blog/enable-template-path-hints-for-frontend-admin-panel-in-magento/). This will show the hints to you and all the customers, so be diligent about doing this live. Secondly, you will need to take a look at the block which encompasses the pricing. When you find the template name, just go to the .phtml file and see what's going on there with the price output.

Answer (score 0):

Edit app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Look for price divs and comment one.